# What is the difference between 租, 租用, 租出, and 租赁, all meaning "to rent"?

Tags: meaning, difference

租  租用  租出 租赁 DIFFERENCE

How to really say rent or hire in Chinese? The other day I found a sentence with 租用 I have not seen before; I always found 租出 or 租 instead.  What is the difference between them?  I also found on the internet e.g. 租赁。 Does it matter if you are the person who rents or the person is renting like in English, or is there a difference?

Answer (score 5):

> Does it matter if you are the person who rents or the person is renting

Yes, there are differences. The main verb is always 租, with different meaning based on different directional complements:

- 租**出去** = to rent **out**, to lease

You use this term when the subject is the one who *lends* something for a fee. Example:

> 我想把我的房子租出去 I want to rent my house (to somebody else)

- 租**下来** = to take out a rent

You use this term when the subject is the one who *borrows* something for a fee. Example:

> 这套房子离你公司很近，还是赶快租下来吧 This house is very close to your workplace, let's rent it now (let's take it)

---

Other words you mention:

- 租赁 = (to) rent, (to) lease —— dictionaries list this as a verb similar to 租用 (to take on lease) and 出租 (to give on lease), though in practice, it's often used in noun phrases such as 租赁合同 lease contract, 租赁条件 lease conditions, etc.
- 租用 = to rent —— with the result complement 用，rent *and use*，I think this is more common in Taiwan

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong, regarding 租赁. According to GF (现代汉语规范词典), 租赁 is a verb. GF gives precisely two meanings: a) 租用 and b) 出租. It gives sample sentences: a) 这家公司租赁了整座写字楼。b) 市公交总公司向外租赁新型大客车。// 现代汉语大词典 also gives the same two meanings

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler I'm aware of that. However in my **practical** experience I've always heard and used 租赁 in noun phrases, exemplified by the surely correct 租赁合同, which is translated in English as "lease contract". Of course I'm not going to argue against a reputable dictionary. As the distinction between verbs and nouns in Chinese is less pronounced than in English, I've always assumed that 租赁 is one those words with a more freely shifting grammatical function.

Answer (score 4):

租: to rent; to rent out. e.g. 我要租屋 (I want to rent a house); 我租給你 (I'll rent it to you)

租用: to rent and use (if you rent a house but not using it for anything, you cannot say you are 租用那个房子)

租借: to rent or borrow; to least or lent

租出: to rent out/ to lease (to someone who rent from you)

租赁: to rent or to lease.  e.g. [房屋租賃](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%88%BF%E5%B1%8B%E7%A7%9F%E8%B5%81) (to rent or lease house); 本店有大量外國 DVD，歡迎租賃  (We have a large number of foreign DVDs, welcome to rent)

Answer (score 1):

租 租用 租出 (出租) 租赁

租 and 租用, pretty similar phrases, eg. 我租了一台車 or 我租用了一台車, 這個房子是租的 or 這個房子是租用的.

租出 means something has been rented by someone. eg. 這個車子租出去了.

出租 could have multiple meanings...

a. same meaning of 租出, eg. 這個車子出租了.

b. for rent, eg. 那個房子等待出租, That house is for renting.

租賃, quite formal phrase, you may see lots of this phrase on rental agreement or contract. It's not so commonly used in DAILY conversation.

Answer (score 0):

租, 租用 is used to express people rent something. For example, 他租了一間房間(He rented a room). 他租用了一間房間(He rented a room.)

租出, 租賃 is used to express people rent out something. For example, 房東把房間租出(Landlord rented out a room.) 房東把房間租賃給別人(Landlord rented out a room to other people.)